# How to configure a rest api parameter that accepts list of string usernames into cozyroc

Tags: ssis, cozyroc

Im trying to configure cozyroc to call rest api in a SSIS project. The api that i intend to call has a request param to accept list of usernames. The username data type is string. I unable to configure the list data type in cozyroc

A proper guidance on configuring the parameter or xml version of the parameters